# Jquery/angular animation bug with timeout/fadein

Tags: jquery, angularjs, animation

I have list that should animate the list when new card is coming and push the array to the left and insert new li to the ul.

The code in the angular directive is :

```
 setTimeout(function () {
                  $('.list').animate({scrollLeft: 90000}, 1500);

      $('#item' + scope.id).hide().animate({width:'toggle'},500, 'swing',
                  function() {
                    console.log( 'changing to visible: ');
                      $(".div_loader").css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(300);
                  });
          }, 10);
```

The problem is when I click the button that enter the new li  to the list ,the list is jump a little bit and then the loader is show up and the new li enter in nice fade in

How can I fix the jumping?  maybe there is other way to do that animate with angular

thanks a lot

Comment: Your code is not valid due to a missing delimiter. `$('#item.id)` -> `$('#item.id')`

Comment: @lin  updated the post

Comment: You should not mix AngularJS with jQuery. Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background Could you create a fiddle or plnkr to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @lin did not find way to do that in angualr  -smth that push the list and keept the empty place with loader until the new item is ready

Comment: Please create a working fiddle or plnkr to reproduce it.